# Como puedo cambiar el texto de un label de un form que se ejecuta al inicio

Tags: c#

Tengo un FORM (principal) que se carga al inicio y un label SIN texto, el texto del label se lo asigno desde otro form.

Lo que normalmente hago es lo siguiente:

```
MiForm ShowF = new MiForm();
ShowF.MiLabel.Text = "Agregue Texto al Label";
```

pero esto solo me funciona para formularios que aun no se han abierto, ya que si lo hago con el formulario que se cargo al inicio no me muestra el texto puesto que entiendo que mando a llamar al FORM nuevamente, es decir lo duplico.
Hay alguna forma de guardar en alguna variable el FORM inicial para poder después tener acceso a sus herramientas y variables publicas desde otro FORM.

Espero y haya sido lo mas claro posible en mi duda

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor del form hijo agrega que vas a recibir un un form de la siguiente manera (tengo rato que no programo en c# asi que no recuerdo exactamente el constructor como esta).

public formHijo(Form formPadre)
{
InitializeComponent();
....
}

cuando abras el formulario hijo osea hagas un
formHijo= new formHijo(this.Form);
formHijo.show() ó showDialog() dependiendo tu caso

ahora si quieres modificar alguno de sus controles, estos los tienes que poner de forma publica

para modificar el form padre desde el hijo podras hacer lo siguiente: formPadre.label.text="Hola";